# Different behavior with send_file and tempfile on local machine vs production server

Tags: python-3.x, flask, pythonanywhere, contextmanager

I have a small Flask application that utilizes Python's TemporaryDirectory to create a zip file and return it to the client. The code snippet looks like this:

```py
import tempfile, os, shutil
def process():
    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory(dir=os.getcwd()) as tmpdir:
        with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory(dir=tmpdir) as wrapper_dir:

            #some processing
            zipfile = shutil.make_archive("azipfile", "zip", wrapper_dir)

        return send_file(zipfile, mimetype="zip", attachment_filename="azipfile.zip", as_attachment=True)
```

It nests 2 temporary directories, zips the inner directory, and sends the zipped file to the user. If I run the app on my machine locally, it behaves as expected and leaves no directories or files behind since both the context manager and tempfile should have cleaned itself up nicely after serving the zipfile.

However when I run this on PythonAnywhere, it will throw this error:

```py
OSError: [Errno 39] Directory not empty: '/home/{user}/{app}/{tempdirectory}'
```

Logically, the error makes sense since the tempdirectory still contains the zipfile but why is there is difference in behavior running it in production versus locally?

Comment: Does you local environment use the Operating System as your production environment?

Comment: Are you running it in different versions of Python? There may be a change in the way TemporaryDirectories are handled between the versions or, as Dave W Smith suggested, above, it may just be different OSs handling the directory deletion differently.

Comment: My local environment is Mojave and the production environments I'm using are Linux I'm pretty sure (PythonAnywhere/ Azure). At first I thought it was because I wasn't including the right packages in my requirements.txt so I tried doing a new pip freeze but still doesn't seem to be working on either environments.